# Google play market the application supported devices are zero (0)

Tags: android, facebook, google-play, facebook-sdk-3.1

I've finished developing my android app and it was ready for publishing it uses facebook SDK and google play services, But after publishing on play store I noticed that the app supported devices are zero '0'

this is my manifest file:

`

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.acceleromotor" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/shake_in"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name="com.osama.shake_in.Main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.osama.shake_in.Post"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:host="com.osama.shake_in"
                android:pathPrefix="/"
                android:scheme="id" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.osama.shake_in.Settings"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="test.Test"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="test.TestII"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" />

    <service
        android:name="com.osama.shake_in.Listener"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="shake-in listener" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

`

- I made sure that it's **not the permissions** because I built an *.apk version without any permissions and I uploaded it to the beta testing and I still have the same problem.
- I also think it's not the package name but I'm not sure about it.

this is the its link on play web store : [shake-in](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.osama.shake_in)

Comment: Just FYI: typo error, you have android.hardware.sensor.acceleromotor while it should be android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Play uses the `uses-feature` elements to remove incompatible devices. In your case, a simple typo is present, causing you to request the non-existent feature `android.hardware.sensor.acceleromotor`. It should instead be `android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer` (note the meter at the end rather than motor):

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" />
```

As per the [list of hardware features](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#hw-features).